# 捨てても捨てても - what does this phrase mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, jlpt, word-usage

I came across this sentence in my JLPT mock test book:

> 今の暮らしにはモノが溢れ、**捨てても捨てても**増え続ける。

I don't understand what kind of grammar and what is the meaning of the bold phrase. It looks like an expression.

Comment: Usually you can translate it "no matter how (much) --".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a phrase to express "despite doing it over and over". You can use it with other verbs e.g. 食べても食べてもお腹がいっぱいにならない、拭いても拭いても落ちない etc

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's an expression that I've never heard before, it just sounds like a straight-forward, emphatically figurative translation.

> In my life right now, (I'm) overflowing/inundated with things; (such that) even if I throw them away [twice for emphasis], they continue increasing.